# changing the order of age-group into normal order

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `df`. in first step I have changed age into age-group and then got sum of each row based on `agegroup` and `gender`.

```
df<- data_frame(age= c(0,1,3,5,6,29,43,12,1,3,5,12,29,43,0,6), pop= c(12,11,33,45,56,54,67,76,65,11,78,90,112,29,70,60),gender=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

changing age into age-group :

```
x <- df$age %/% 5
x <- pmax(0, pmin(20, x))
df$agegroup<- c(paste(0:19*5, 1:20*5-1, sep="-"), "+100")[x+1]
```

sum of each row:

```
df1 <- aggregate(formula = pop ~ gender  + agegroup, data = df, FUN = sum)

     gender agegroup   pop
1       1      0-4     146
2       2      0-4     56
3       1    10-14     90
4       2    10-14     76
5       1    25-29    112
6       2    25-29     54
7       1    40-44     29
8       2    40-44     67
9       1      5-9    138
10      2      5-9    101
```

as shown in df1, the age-group `5-9` is located after `40-44` but I want to have ordered age-group. my desired output would be like this :

```
      gender  agegroup pop
1       1      0-4     146
2       2      0-4      56
3       1      5-9     138
4       2      5-9     101
5       1     10-14     90
6       2     10-14     76
7       1     25-29    112
8       2     25-29     54
9       1     40-44     29
10      2     40-44     67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to set `agegroup` to a factor and specify the factor order. One way to do this is with `reorder()`.  For example

```
df$agegroup <- reorder(df$agegroup, 
   as.numeric(gsub("-\\d+","", df$agegroup)))
```

We use `gsub()` to take off the second number, and then we can use that to sort by the numeric value of the first number.

Once you've updated the level order to be what you want, you should get the results in the order you want.

```
levels(df$agegroup)
# [1] "0-4"   "5-9"   "10-14" "25-29" "40-44"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am kind of reinventing the wheel here for something that you have already solved but you can use `cut` and pass breaks and labels to it.

The benefit of using `cut` is that it will give you factor levels which are already in the order that you want, you just need to `arrange` them.

```
library(dplyr)

x1 <- c(0, seq(4, 100, 5))
labels <- c(paste(x1[-length(x1)] + 1, x1[-1], sep = '-'), '100+')
labels[1] <- '0-4'

df %>%
  group_by(gender, agegroup = cut(age, c(x1, Inf), labels, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(pop = sum(pop)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(agegroup)

#   gender agegroup   pop
#    <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
# 1      1 0-4        146
# 2      2 0-4         56
# 3      1 5-9        138
# 4      2 5-9        101
# 5      1 10-14       90
# 6      2 10-14       76
# 7      1 25-29      112
# 8      2 25-29       54
# 9      1 40-44       29
#10      2 40-44       67
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mixedorder` from `gtools`

```
df1[gtools::mixedorder(df1$agegroup),]
   gender agegroup pop
1       1      0-4 146
2       2      0-4  56
9       1      5-9 138
10      2      5-9 101
3       1    10-14  90
4       2    10-14  76
5       1    25-29 112
6       2    25-29  54
7       1    40-44  29
8       2    40-44  67
```